# Load different json schemas in PIG

Tags: json, hadoop, apache-pig

I would like to know how to read different Json schemes from one File In PIG.
In Hadoop I would use an jsonparser and with if questions I would find out what kind of json Element it is.

The Json Elements inside one Doccument Are:

```
{"a": "bla", "e": 123, "f": 333}        
{ "a": "bla", "c": "aa"}
```

I Tried to load the first Json Array with the following Command:

```
A = load '/usr/local/hadoop/stuff.net' USING USING JsonLoader('a:chararray, e:int, f:int');
DUMP A;
```

It Throws The Error: ERROR 2088: Fetch failed. Couldn't retrieve result

The Second query is working:

```
B = load '/home/hadoop/Desktop/aaa' USING JsonLoader('a:chararray, c:chararray');
DUMP B;
```

But it also shows me results from the first statement.

So I wanted to ask how to load different Json schemas from the same file or isn't that possible?

Answer (score 0):

I think that you can use Twitter's **elephantbird project**. Some examples you can find [here](https://gist.github.com/neilkod).

Usage is quite easy, you just register jar file and than you can use elephant UDF function to load nested json:

```
REGISTER 'elephant-bird.jar';
json_file_00 = LOAD 'json_file.json' USING com.twitter.elephantbird.pig.load.JsonLoader('-nestedLoad');
json_file_01 = FOREACH json_file_00 GENERATE json_file_00#'fieldName' AS field_name;
```

I am also using [**akela project**](https://github.com/mozilla-metrics/akela) from mozilla which is great but outdated.